# Error importing CSS modules with Storybook webpack 5

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook, css-loader, webpack-5

I am using Storybook with webpack 5 for a simple project and I'm having challenges with CSS module imports despite customising the webpack config for storybook.

```
(2:7) src/stories/header.css Unknown word

  1 | 
> 2 |       import API from "!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
    |       ^
  3 |       import domAPI from "!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";
  4 |       import insertFn from "!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";

    at processResult (./node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:743:19)
    at ./node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:844:5
    at ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at ./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (./node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at Object.loader (./node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:155:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:61:5)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@storybook/builder-webpack5/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
CssSyntaxError
```

My main.js file looks like this

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.mdx', '../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: 'webpack5',
  },
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    const path = require('path');

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
    });
    return config;};
  },
};
```

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same error and it was caused by accidentally using the `@nrwl/react/plugins/storybook` twice, which lead to duplicate webpack loader rules so I am guessing that `framework: '@storybook/react'` already sets up loaders for `.css` files and then you are adding your own loader here

```
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
});
```

which first uses `css-loader`, then `style-loader` and then it gets passed to the rule that is already in place by the `@storybook/react` framework which again uses `css-loader`, but the input of this loader is the output of the `style-loader` from your rule. You can actually see this in the error

```
(2:7) src/stories/header.css Unknown word

  1 | 
> 2 |       import API from "!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";
    |       ^
  3 |       import domAPI from "!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/styleDomAPI.js";
  4 |       import insertFn from "!../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/insertBySelector.js";
```

because `css-loader` is expecting a CSS file but `style-loader` outputs JS file and therefore it throws error `Unknown word` because `import` is invalid CSS word.

So to fix you issue, you probably need to remove your custom rule for CSS files, because it's already included in the rules.

Comment: I have had the same issue, I realized double configuration caused that as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storybook 7 with webpack 5, a simpler solution would be looking at [Styling-Webpack](https://storybook.js.org/addons/@storybook/addon-styling-webpack) addon on which will configure storybook with CSS modules for you.